# Is there an MSBuild macro for build date/time?

Tags: macros, msbuild

Suppose I have a build script with a Target section like the following:

```
    <Target Name="AssemblyVersionMAIN" Inputs="@(AssemblyVersionFiles)" Outputs="UpdatedAssemblyVersionFiles">
        <Attrib Files="%(AssemblyVersionFiles.FullPath)" Normal="true"/>
        <AssemblyInfo
            CodeLanguage="CS"
            OutputFile="%(AssemblyVersionFiles.FullPath)"
            AssemblyProduct="$(ProductName)"
            AssemblyTitle="$(ProductName)"
            AssemblyCompany="$(CompanyName)"
            AssemblyCopyright="© $(CompanyName) 2014"  <!-- THIS LINE -->
            AssemblyVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)"
            AssemblyFileVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)"
            AssemblyInformationalVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)">
            <Output TaskParameter="OutputFile" ItemName="UpdatedAssemblyVersionFiles"/>
        </AssemblyInfo>
    </Target>
```

At the moment, the year is static and has to be changed manually. Is there a simple way of replacing "2014" with something like $(Year)? I've checked the MSBuild reference but nothing jumps out at me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you are using MsBuild 4 you could also use a property function for this, like e.g.:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CurrentDate>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd"))</CurrentDate>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Just format the recieved date as you need it. There are also plenty of other functions available, see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440(v=vs.100).aspx.

Comment: How would I get that value into my `AssemblyCopyright` variable, as I do in this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22613738/37971)?

Comment: You were quicker than me ;-). Either the way you solved it or, if you need it more times, define a property that you can use throughout your build file.

Also don't forget to marrk the question as solved (either yours or mine, doesn't matter to me). If the answer was helpful, I would appreciate also an upvoting, as I'm quite new here.

Comment: That syntax looks like a fragment of PowerShell. I have found that you can also use `[System.DateTimeOffset]` to capture the UTC offset of the build time, even though it's not documented in the linked MSDN page. I suspect that you can probably run arbitrary PowerShell code, rather than the limited subset described in the docs.

Answer (score 6):

Since I'm using MSBuild Community Tasks and MSBuild 4, I can substitute the following:

```
AssemblyCopyright="© $(CompanyName) $([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(`yyyy`))"
```

which seems to work.

Comment: I suspect this should use `'` instead of backticks in the delimiters around the format specifier